# Not receiving remote push notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently rewriting my app from Objective-C to Swift and working on notifications. For some reason Swift version of the app is not receiving any remote push notifications while Objective-C version does.

Here's the code I'm using to register for notifications in AppDelegate:

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.badge, .alert, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options, completionHandler: { granted, error in
        print("access granted: \(granted)")
    })
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

I assume that the app successfully registers because `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method gets called. But when I try to send the test notification using the token I got from that method, I don't get actual notification on device.

Also none of these methods get called:

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) {

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the correct certificate (development aps cert) to push?

Answer (score 1):

you say that you are not receiving so let's first make sure that those methods you mention before that are not being called are comming from here `extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` (By the way when you do implement the **didReceive** method make sure you call the `completionHandler()` at the end)

When you do this:

> application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

Make sure to run it from the **main thread**, as it can be called if not specified from the background and that might fail. You can do so by doing

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
  UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

I'll assume that you are **getting the device token** this way or something similar:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // 1. Convert device token to string
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        // 2. Print device token to use for PNs payloads
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
}
```

Finally implement this method to see if there are any errors while registering the device

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        // 1. Print out error if PNs registration not successful
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications with error: \(error)")
 }
```

Oh by the way (just in case you have missed it) make sure you enabled in your project's target the push notification.

Comment: Yes, I've done everything you described. Still no result

Comment: Maybe [this step by step tutorial](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/ios-remote-push-notifications-in-a-nutshell-d05f5ccac252) can help you notice what you are missing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled Push notification in your project setting capabilities.
How to enable: 
go to target: -> select project -> go to capabilities -> go to Push Notification. enable it there.

Another thing is the certificate. While development you should not Production certificates.